# Where did I go wrong with this cipher program?

Tags: java

I need to write a program that takes the first, middle, and last name of a person and encrypt it: each letter the user enters is shifted circularly by the selected key. For example, if the key is 1 and the original letter is ‘A’, then the encrypted letter will be ‘B’. If the key is 3 and the original letter is ‘b’, then the encrypted letter will be ‘e’. If the key is 3 and the original letter is ‘z’, then the encrypted letter will be ‘c’.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class  Cipher {
    public static void main(String []main){
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        String firstname = console.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your middle name: ");
        String middlename = console.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
        String lastname = console.nextLine();
        System.out.print("enter the key ");
        int N = console.nextInt();
        String s = firstname + middlename + lastname;
        System.out.print("your original name is "+ s);
        String empty = "";
        for( int i = 0; i<=s.length();i++){
            if (s.charAt(i)!=' '){
                System.out.print(empty ="" + s.charAt(i));
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(empty +=s.charAt(i+N));
            }

              }
            System.out.print("encrypted name is " + empty);
    }
}
```

My problem seems to be in the loop, but I have no idea how to fix it.

What I am getting:

```
Enter your first name: a
Enter your middle name: b
Enter your last name: c
enter the key 2
your original name is abcaababcException in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 3
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at test1.test.main(test.java:19)
```

While what I should be getting for example is the following:

```
Enter your first name: a
Enter your middle name: b
Enter your last name: c
enter the key 2
your original name is abc
encrypted name is cde
```

Comment: Consider improving your question by telling us what behavior your expecting, and what you're actually seeing, as well as what steps you've taken to try to debug your program.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels edited the main question, and placed expected output and what i am getting

Comment: Predator, your error message is key. It tells you to look at line 19 of your program, that you're trying to get a character in a String that is beyond the length of a String. Note that Strings and arrays are 0 based, and so a String of length 3 will have characters at positions 0, 1, and 2. You're trying to look at position 3 since your for loop goes to `<=` the length of the String. Use `<` instead. Change `for( int i = 0; i <= s.length();i++){` to `for( int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){`

Comment: thank you :) 
@HovercraftFullOfEels how can i use unicode to create new characters in the program, so i be able to encrypt the string as required?

Comment: Unicode? You can just use char's from your String and shift them. You'll need a bottom char and a top char, ones that encompass all the chars you're interested in, and then do a little simple math to rotate them or un-rotate them. Experiment, play, have fun with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using this code instead of your last `for-loop` :

```
    byte[] input = s.getBytes();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
        input[i]+= N;
    }

    String encrypted = new String(input);
    System.out.print("encrypted name is " + encrypted);
```

Should be fine on ASCII symbol sets.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this:

```
s.charAt(i+N)
```

Since it will access characters that are 'after' the string - you may use indices from `0` to `s.length()`